# Easy way to view parameter to argument mapping

Tags: java, eclipse

In *Eclipse*, is there an easy way to see the parameter - argument mapping in a method call?

For example, assume a method defined as:

```
public String myMethod(
        String p1,
        String p2,
        String p3
    );
```

Somewhere else, it is referenced as (*the method call*):

```
String myOutput = myMethod(
        arg3,
        anObject.getArg2(),
        "myString"
    );
```

The hypothetical feature would display the mappings as follows (maybe when mouse pointer hovers on the method call):

```
String myMethod(String p1, String p2, String p3)
    p1: arg3
    p2: anObject.getArg2()
    p3: "myString"
```

I believe this would be very useful for methods that take a lot of arguments. Often I have to manually count and check the position to ensure each argument is assigned to the correct parameter.

**EDIT:** This question is **not** about code practices or code refactoring. It is about whether *Eclipse* provides a feature to quickly view the mapping between arguments in a method call and the parameters in the method definition.

Comment: The main problems are 1. that your methods take too many arguments, 2. that your formatting doesn't make that clear. Write one argument per line, and it will be much more readable (Eclipse can even autoformat this way for you). And use objects to group your arguments, or the builder pattern, or whatever OO technique that reduces the number of arguments a method takes.

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. It's not about the code practices, but whether Eclipse provides an easy way to see the mapping between arguments in a method call and the parameters in the method definition, something similar to a JavaDoc pop-up. For your record, the above are just examples. In actual code, we write one argument per line, and we use builder patterns, beans and what not. **That is not the issue here.** We still can't see the mapping quickly, without having to count and ensure order of the arguments one by one.

Comment: @ADTC: First, there is no such feature I am aware of in Eclipse. Second, you are misunderstanding JB Nizet. According to clean code rules (read Robert C. Martin's book about it) you should never have methods that take so much arguments. So you should take effort to minimize the method argument count, so you just do not need that feature. [I know, this comment is somewhat unsatisfying, but it's the truth.]

Comment: My point is that, if your method takes 2 or 3 arguments at the maximum, the mapping is obvious and doesn't need any specific tool to be understood. Just put your cursor between the parentheses, type the keyboard shortcut used to suggest arguments, and the mapping between the argument names and the actual arguments will be obvious. IIRC, this shortcut is Ctrl-Shift-Space, but I'm an IntelliJ user now, so I might be wrong.

Comment: I just want to say that my question is purely to know whether such a feature exists (and I didn't find it yet). I didn't ask it to have the code practices evaluated or improved, or to debate whether such a feature would be useful or not. _On a sidenote,_ it's easy to say 'follow good code practices' but many programmers are stuck with huge codebases that had been built on bad practices from the beginning, and changing them would take a lot of manpower. Please keep this in mind when you admonish someone for apparently following bad code practices - he may simply be forced to comply.

Comment: Well if you use java doc in your code, eclipse will help you a lot. If you select the method to call via autocomplete (ctrl + space) it shows the whole signature in a tool tip. It autosuggests variable names (which should imply what the argument is there for). If you walk through the method call, you see which argument you are at. But JB and Seelenvirtuose are right, the better the code base, the easier those tasks are, so even with a grown code base. Keep refactoring and use java doc on those interfaces and things get considerably easier after some time,

Comment: Thanks Matthias. Unfortunately I can't bring that tooltip up for method calls already written. If I hit Ctrl-Space on an existing method call, it only shows the proposals. Quite useless unless I'm writing a fresh new call to the method. **PS:** I know they are right about code practices. It's just that this question is not about that. :)

Comment: @ADTC: If it “only shows the proposals” you have to *select* one of the proposals. Then you can use the arrow keys to navigate through the arguments. I know, it’s a bit tricky as you have to guess the right method in case of overloading. But placing the cursor after the last comma (before the last argument) before hitting `ctrl`+`space` can reduce the numbers of possibilities dramatically.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! :D That works well even if it's not what I originally intended, and although I have to select the correct method (the pain of which is eased a little by your second tip). You could make it an answer!